# BIOS unable to boot CD or Hard Drive

Tags: boot, motherboard, bios

Motherboard Intel DQ35MP.
HDD Caviar Green 1TB.

I'm having problems with my BIOS and/or hard drive/disc drive.

Came back from a trip, booted my computer, and realized that the **BIOS wasn't booting anymore**, just a black screen with no beep sounds. Only fans and lights on. Then I thought it might be caused by the video card, I removed it, and still no BIOS screen. Then **I removed the hard drive and voila BIOS screen is back** again. If the hard drive is defective then I can check that with a Rescue Disk. I inserted the CD on the Disc Tray but the computer did not respond to it, **the screen freezes in black with an "E7" string** at the bottom right corner just after the BIOS screen, this happens with or without discs.

BIOS settings are set to default, and CD reading is on top of the boot device list.

**EDIT**

I removed the BIOS battery, rebooted the CPU, the BIOS screen showed up, and then it freezed in E7. Placed the BIOS batttery, rebooted and same thing, we are stuck with the E7 string.

**I uploaded a video to illustrate the problem**
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=13jPdBcIrBU

[image: E7 of death]
[image: E7 of death]

Comment: did you try another cd?

Comment: yes I did, same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

removing hd and cd-rom : not solved

updating the bios: not solved

Last steps:

1. remove everything: any pci, pci express, memory, cpu, mouse, keyboard, power cables, etc
2. add the very minimum to it to boot: power cables, the fewest memory necessary (I don't know if your board requires one or two memory modules), cpu.
3. turn it on and see what happens.

Comment: Already tried those combinations Woliveira, and the result is the same. "E7"

Comment: added another possibilities

Comment: @Gabriel: you have tried to reset the BIOS / CMOS? The manual says how to do it: remove battery, change some jumper, turn computer on. http://downloadmirror.intel.com/15037/eng/DQ35MP_TechProdSpec.pdf , p.51 of the pdf

Comment: I'm currently updating the BIOS with the "F7" method. I will tell you what happens as soon as I'm done.

Comment: Even thought I could not see the update process (Sometimes happens as some Intel guys stated in a video), the BIOS updated to the latest version, unfortunately It did no effect to the "E7" issue.

Comment: I removed everything, only one RAM, and integrated VGA, same E7 screen.

Comment: I think the motherboard is defective, I bought a new IDE cable to try again with the Hard Drive and nothing.

Comment: If you can't boot even using the simplest configuration (CPU + ram + onboard vga), then it might be: cpu, ram, onboard vga, or the motherboard. But to test it you need another motherboard (to test cpu, ram) or another cpu / ram to test the motherboard. I'd bet on the motherboard problem.

Comment: Yeah me too, I tested using my video card, the result was the same. Do you know of any good inexpensive heat resistant motherboard which allows overclocking? I need IDE and SATA connections, and my video card is VGA.

Comment: hard to recomend one to another country (I live in brazil). Take a look at asus P8H67-M EVO

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried removing the BIOS battery and restarting, and then putting it back in to do like a fresh reset of the BIOS? That may solve your problem.

Comment: A new BIOS battery (CR2032).

Comment: I removed the BIOS battery, rebooted the CPU, the BIOS screen showed up, and then it freezed in E7. Placed the BIOS batttery, rebooted same thing. The computer is stuck with the E7 string.

Comment: Maybe RAM related problems... http://www.evga.com/forums/tm.aspx?m=36452&mpage=1

Comment: I removed all my Ram memory cards, and placed one by one, the "E7" remained.

Answer (score 0):

Remove power cord and battery, hold the power button down for a minute or two, replace the power cord and battery and power on. What happens this time?

Comment: Same problem, but something came out differently if remove the battery I can get past the "E7 string" with a firmware message "The CMOS Battery has been removed". Does this mean that the battery is the cause of the ilness?

Comment: No, not likely. I'm sorry, for some reason I thought this was a laptop, and the above troubleshooting step is primarily for laptops. At the very worst you can try a new battery. They're generally only a few dollars. But I would not bet on it being the battery.